# Cannot open resource file

Tags: qt, qt5

Here is my code:

```
QFile test("://needle.png"); // also tried :/needle.png :\needle.png :\\needle.png

if(test.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "yay";
} else {
    qDebug() << "fail";
}
```

I have this in my project file:

```
RESOURCES += Resources.qrc
```

Here is my QRC file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>needle.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I keep getting fail as output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the URL notation

```
QFile test("qrc:///needle.png");
```

work for you?

Comment: Turns out the project was corrupted.

Comment: I just tried out your code and it worked fine for me. Of course, I used `QFile test(":/needle.png");`. I think your code - as posted here - is OK. Where are your qrc and png files located? What's the content of your pro file?

Comment: Saw your second comment too late. So, all is fine ;)

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem. Running qmake again finally worked (build -> run qmake).

Comment: I can't believe it, wasted so much time when all I needed to do was run qmake. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the project.user.pro file, reopened QT.  And it chose the kit and rebuilt.  Working now.