# Read text file in textedit Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I have this text file:

```
Name 1      Email 1
Name 2      Email 2
Name 3      Email 3
Name 4      Email 4
Name 5      Email 5
```

This is a list of employees with their emails. I want to make a list in a dialog window with their names displayed there. I thought this was a good way to print out the text file on the dialog window but it isn't working.

employees_dialog.cpp

```
#include "employees_dialog.h"
#include "ui_employees_dialog.h"
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>


employees_dialog::employees_dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::employees_dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    getTextFile();
}

employees_dialog::~employees_dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void employees_dialog::getTextFile()
{
    QFile myFile(":/employees.txt");
    myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream textStream(&myFile);
    QString line = textStream.readAll();
    myFile.close();
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(line);
}
```

This is the header file.

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEES_DIALOG_H
#define EMPLOYEES_DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
    class employees_dialog;
}

class employees_dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit employees_dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~employees_dialog();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::employees_dialog *ui;
    void getTextFile();
};

#endif // EMPLOYEES_DIALOG_H
```

So the `textEdit` in the UI should display the text file. But it's just blank white. I have the file in Qt Resources File. The debugger doesn't give any errors the application itself is just working fine but the text won't appear in the `textEdit`.

By the way, I'm new to Qt.

Comment: test for file open errors

Comment: I would use a debugger. Set a breakpoint on getTextFile() and examine the contents of line. I suspect the QFile is not being open because of a problem with the qrc file.

Comment: if(QFile::exists(true))
    {
        qDebug("File doesnt exists or wont open");
    }

Comment: this doesnt work it says
'F:\Scripts\Berichtencentrumemployees_dialog.cpp:30: error: C2665: 'QFile::exists' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
c:\qt\qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\include\qtcore\qfile.h(108): could be 'bool QFile::exists(const QString &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(bool)''

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg just `myFile.exists()` instead of `QFile::exists(true)`

Comment: Oke the file doesn't exists what did do wrong? I did make a qrc file

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989149/cannot-open-resource-file ?

Comment: I checked it and did the same. But it still isnt working

Comment: Even after following all these steps. How can I solve this problem to open the file? Or should I upload the Project?

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg could you show your `qrc` file? Did not you forget about resource prefix in `QFile` constructor's argument?

Comment: @johny <RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>employees.txt</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg Does your `pro` file contain string like `RESOURCES += YourResourceFilename.qrc`?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
QFile file( "myfile.txt" );

if ( !file.exists() )
{
    qDebug()<<"doesn't exist the file";
}
```